# Problemas ao validar saldo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, beleza pessoal?

Estou com um problema em meu código, estou fazendo uma validação para verificar se a quantidade inserida pelo usuário é maior que o saldo, se for eu envio um erro para o usuário.

O código é o seguinte :

```
                    $('#txb' + sequencia).on('change', function () {

                    var saldo = $($('#tbPimItem tbody tr td').get(7)).text();
                    var qtde = $(this).val();

                    console.log(qtde > saldo);

                    if (qtde > saldo) {

                        var mensagem = {
                            Tipo: 'A',
                            Mensagem: 'Atenção, a quantidade não pode ser maior que o saldo.'
                        };
                        console.log();

                        $(this).val(saldo);
                        exibirMensagem(mensagem, 100);
                    }

                });
```

Ele está dentro desse código:

```
$(result.Retorno.PimItem).each(function () {

                sequencia++;

                $('#tbPimItem tbody').append($('<tr style="cursor:pointer"></tr >')

                    .append($('<td><input type="checkbox" id="cb' + sequencia +'" /></td>'))
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.Sequencia))
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.Item.Id))
                    .append($('<td style="width:80px;"><input type="number" max="3" id="txb' + sequencia + '" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" /></td>'))                    
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.Item.Descricao))
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.DescricaoComplementar))
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.Ordem.Id))                      
                    .append($('<td></td>').text(this.Item.Saldo))   
                );  

                $('#txb' + sequencia).val(this.Item.Saldo);

                $('#txb' + sequencia).on('change', function () {

                    var saldo = $($('#tbPimItem tbody tr td').get(7)).text();
                    var qtde = $(this).val();

                    console.log(qtde > saldo);

                    if (qtde > saldo) {

                        var mensagem = {
                            Tipo: 'A',
                            Mensagem: 'Atenção, a quantidade não pode ser maior que o saldo.'
                        };
                        console.log();

                        $(this).val(saldo);
                        exibirMensagem(mensagem, 100);
                    }

                });

                if (this.Item.Saldo !== 0) return;
                $('#' + sequencia).prop('disabled', true); 
                $('#cb' + sequencia).prop('disabled', true);

            });
```

Meu problema é :

O saldo é igual a 3, quando digito 4 ele valida, quando digito 10 ele não valida. Se digito 30 ele valida.

é como se ele verifica-se apenas o primeiro digito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tens de usar numeros na comparação e não texto (strings). Uma sugestão seria:

```js
var saldo = $('#tbPimItem tbody tr td::last-of-type').text();
var qtde = this.value;

console.log(Number(qtde) > Number(saldo));
```

Answer (score 1):

A comparação está sendo feito entre strings, você pode fazer cast para *Number*:

```
var saldo = parseFloat($($('#tbPimItem tbody tr td').get(7)).text());
var qtde = parseFloat($(this).val());
```